# Convert java to groovy

Tags: java, groovy, oauth, scribe

I'm trying to run the java code below in groovy.  I believe that I've properly imported the class and added the necessary jar files to the classpath.  However, I'm still getting compilation errors.

Java code:

```
package com.tradeking;

this.class.classLoader.rootLoader.addURL( new URL("file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Groovy/Groovy-2.4.0/lib/commons-codec-1.10.jar") )
this.class.classLoader.rootLoader.addURL( new URL("file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Groovy/Groovy-2.4.0/lib/scribe-1.3.7.jar") )

import org.scribe.builder.*;
import org.scribe.model.*;
import org.scribe.oauth.*;
import org.scribe.builder.api.DefaultApi10a;
import org.scribe.model.Token;



public class TradeKingApi extends DefaultApi10a
{
    private static final String CONSUMER_KEY = "***";
    private static final String CONSUMER_SECRET = "***";
    private static final String OAUTH_TOKEN = "***";
    private static final String OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = "***";

private static final String PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL = "https://api.tradeking.com/v1/market/ext/quotes.xml";

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
                            .provider(TradeKingApi.class)
                            .apiKey("***")
                            .apiSecret("***")
                            .build();
    Token accessToken = new Token("***", "***");

    }
}
```

When I run the above, I get the following errors:

```
3 compilation errors:

Abstract method 'java.lang.String getRequestTokenEndpoint()' is not implemented but a method of the same name but different return type is defined: method 'java.lang.String getRequestTokenEndpoint()'
 at line: -1, column: -1

Abstract method 'java.lang.String getAuthorizationUrl(org.scribe.model.Token)' is not implemented but a method of the same name but different return type is defined: method 'java.lang.String getAuthorizationUrl(org.scribe.model.Token)'
 at line: -1, column: -1

Abstract method 'java.lang.String getAccessTokenEndpoint()' is not implemented but a method of the same name but different return type is defined: method 'java.lang.String getAccessTokenEndpoint()'
 at line: -1, column: -1
```

Thank you for any hints or suggestions.

Comment: _what_ does not work?  errors?  traces? ...

Comment: When I run the above, I get the following error: 1 compilation error:unable to resolve class DefaultApi10a at line: 7, column: 4

Comment: please edit the question and add the error message there.  also provide a full trace, if available and also try to annotate in the source code, what lines/column the trace refers to.

Comment: Thanks very much for looking at my code.  I made your suggested edits to the question.  Also, I tried to get the full stack trace by selecting "Show Full Stack Traces" from the view menu, but it didn't work.  Additionally, I searched for the "stacktrace.log" file on my c drive but couldn't locate it.  How can I get the full stack trace?  Do I need to run some groovy code prior to running the java code?  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

according to `https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/src/main/java/org/scribe/builder/api/DefaultApi10a.java` you have to import this class properly.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I'll review the code as well as the referenced javadocs.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you have a classpath problem at compile time.

This means that the compiler cannot find a definition of the class that you are trying to extend `DefaultApi10a`.

A quick google tells me that this class is in package `org.scribe.builder`, which you have imported at the top of your class.

You need to add jar files to the classpath of your build environment in order for the compiler to be able to resolve the classes that you have imported.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts.  I added two lines of code my program to add the necessary jar files to the class path.  However, I'm still getting the exact same error.  "unable to resolve class DefaultApi10a"

Comment: I believe that I fixed the issue with DefaultApi10a.  Now getting different errors.  Updated log is above.

Comment: It looks like you now resolve the class, however the class defines abstract methods which need to be implemented by your class.